# Checking the version in the Camera

Tags: java, android, kotlin, camera, version

I need to work with versions below 28 for Camera, how do I write this in else {} ?
I need version 21 and above, for example

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
```

fun View.padWithDisplayCutout() {

```
fun doPadding(cutout: DisplayCutout) = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    setPadding(
        cutout.safeInsetLeft,
        cutout.safeInsetTop,
        cutout.safeInsetRight,
        cutout.safeInsetBottom
    )
} else {
     ?????????????????????????????????????????
}

rootWindowInsets?.displayCutout?.let { doPadding(it) }

setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { _, insets ->
    insets.displayCutout?.let { doPadding(it) }
    insets
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

[DisplayCutout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/DisplayCutout) was introduced in API lvl 28, this class isn't achievable on lower Android versions, as these aren't supporting display cutouts, so you probably should remove `else{...}`, it will be no-op anyway

in fact your `doPadding` method won't be called on lower system versions, as you are calling it by

```
insets.displayCutout?.let { doPadding(it) }
```

or

```
rootWindowInsets?.displayCutout?.let { doPadding(it) }
```

and on lower Androids < API28 `displayCutout` will always be `null` and `let` won't execute

Comment: are you sure that `rootWindowInsets?.displayCutout?` actually will be `null`? I would expect it would throw an exception on Android < API28

Comment: @Ivo Beckers - now I'm not shure, worth trying...